# How to specify TreatWarningsAsErrors on MSBuild 12 command line

Tags: msbuild

I have a vb.net project in my solution that contains issues that create compiler warnings.

I have set the "Treat Warnings As Errors" to true in the Compile Page of the project settings in visual studio.

When I build either the Debug or Release configuration in Visual Studio 2012 I get errors reported.

When I build the Release congif in Visual 2013 I get the errors. When I build in Debug config I get nothing. This seems like a bug in VS2013.

When I run with MSBuild in the command line (either version 4 or version 12) it just reports warnings, no matter which configuration. I have tried various things found while googling:

```
msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"
msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true
msbuild /t:Rebuild /t:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"
msbuild /t:Rebuild /t:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true
```

Nothing I have tried has revealed the results I would like. I'm not sure why MSBuild doesn't use the settings in the .csproj file.

What is the correct way to have comiler warnings treaded as errors when building with MBBuild from the command line?

Comment: The first one is correct syntax. `msbuild your.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"`. What warnings exactly do you want as errors? This flag only controls compilation warnings but not generic MSBuild warnings.

Comment: Yes, compiler errors. When I run: msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release I get 46 warnings no errors.  But, when I run msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;TreatWarningsAsErrors="true" I get 0 Warnings, 0 Errors.

Also strange, I don't get the warnings when I run a debug build. It appears the .aspx forms aren't compiled during debug build?